# Run JDT ASTVisitor on the output of Java Compiler

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt, java-compiler-api

I am trying to write an extended Java Compiler that gives all the errors and warnings from javac plus some errors for custom unsupported java features.

Since this is going to run on a server, i would like to generate the syntax tree only once in order to get a better performance. Right now, I am extending the class **javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor** in order to generate my custom errors using the ProcessingEnvironment Object generated by the JavaCompiler API

I implemented this using the TreeScanner class provided by sun. However this is not ideal since the implementation is not open source, not included in all JDKs and there is no guarantee it will work with future versions of the Java Compiler API.

Thats why I tried to use **org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser** instead of the parser provided by sun but I didnt find a way to use the ProcessingEnvironment Object generated by the JavaCompiler API.

Does anyone know how to do this or alternatively how to generate all compiler errors and warnings just using jdt?

If you know a different library that could help me solve this problem, that would also help me a lot!

Im sorry if this question has already been asked here, I have been searching for a day now but couldnt find a better solution than using the implementation from sun

Comment: The JDT ASTParser does not use javac at all. It is a completely separate Java parser with its own APIs.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. Do you know how to generate javac like outputs just using jdt?

Comment: No, I don't. I don't use JavaCompiler or JDT enough to know.

Comment: Is your problem that you don't get any error messages from ASTParser, or do you definitely need the messages to be the exact same form as javac emits?

Comment: Hi @stephan thanks for your reply. I was able to generate my custom errors but I am still using the Java Compiler API to generate all the javac emits, which means my server has to parse the source code twice. I was wondering if I could get the jdt implementation to generate syntax errors and Xlint warnings without having to reimplement javac ;). They dont need to be the exact same as javac tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDT's `ASTParser` to create a `CompilationUnit`, just ask it [`getProblems()`](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/CompilationUnit.html#getProblems--) and you should get all the errors / warnings / infos that JDT detected in the code.

Note, that you may want to tweak the options passed into `ASTParser.setCompilerOptions()`. The possible options are described by constants in class `JavaCore`, in particular everything resembling javac's Xlint options has a constant starting with `COMPILER_PB..`. You'll find these options documented in the [online help](https://help.eclipse.org/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_options.htm?cp=3_0_0_7).

As a side effect, you may even see a few useful warnings which javac does not emit, if you choose to enable the corresponding options.